# Fedora 20: Anyway to install the default tools which comes with Fedora-Gnome on Cinnamon?

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop

I just did a fresh install of Fedora 20 and chose Cinnamon as my desktop. To my surprise, Gnome was not install at all.. and thus I feel am I missing a bunch of "stuff" that's normally included in a default Fedora install (w. Gnome). Is there any way I can "fill the gaps" without actually installing the Gnome desktop itself? If so, how? If not, will installing the Gnome desktop itself give me what I am looking for; ie. all the stuff (apps, programs, options, etc) you would get in a default Fedora install? If so, then what's the best way to install the Gnome desktop in my situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can install programs (any file owned by a package, really) by name, i.e., `yum install /usr/bin/ssh-add` will install `openssh-clients` (and everything else needed for that). But consider that pulling in "useful parts of Gnome" will probably drag most of Gnome along.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, this should install a few useful things:

```
sudo yum install gedit gparted cups* pdfmod k3b firefox gnome-terminal libreoffice libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw libreoffice-writer libreoffice-math libreoffice-impress thunderbird libreoffice-opensymbol-fonts rhythmbox vlc
```

These may be useful as well, but might try and install bits of the gnome desktop as dependencies:

```
sudo yum install nautilus nautilus-actions nautilus-sendto nautilus-extensions file-roller evolution totem
```

I would recommend just searching for what you want using:

```
sudo yum search <SEARCH-TERM>
```

and then installing those packages you want with:

```
sudo yum install <NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gnome should be installed as group "GNOME Desktop" on Fedora. To check *subgroups* and its packages use:

```
# list mandatory gnome groups
yum groups info GNOME\ Desktop
# list packages from mandatory group
yum groups info gnome-desktop
```

There you have a list of package and you can choose these you want. But be careful for dependencies - some of them needs gnome itself.